# How to show ts_dimensions attributes in product edit panel?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have a three attributes:  [image]
How can I show them in Product Editor?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ts_dimensions_height` , `ts_dimensions_width` , `ts_dimensions_length` is a default magento attribute. by default it is showing in while add or edit products.

But it is not showing in while add or edit product then go to **Admin > Store > Attributes > Attribute set** here you can see list of attribute set which is used in while adding or edit product.

Edit attribute set **default**  and in the right side, you can see list of an attribute. just drag & drop attribute to the center column and save attribute set.

That's it, now you can see **td_dimensions** attributes in your product form.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Already done. Even when product have attribute set with ts_dimensions attributes, they not show in admin panel.

Comment: It might be a chance some external extension is conflict.

Comment: Mb solution create your own attributes for w/h/l and try to show them?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes `ts_dimensions_length` / `ts_dimensions_width` / `ts_dimensions_height` are part of the `Temando_Shipping` module that ships with Magento 2.

[ *Source:* Line 32 - 34 in `vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Setup/SetupData.php` ]

[image: Line 32 - 34 Temando_Shipping SetupData.php]

**To View a Desired Product Attribute(s) in the Product_Summary_Grid Page :**

Login to Magento Admin UIX (aka Magento Backend) -> Stores -> Attributes : Product -> Search for the Attribute_Id of interest -> Click on the row (in the Attributes Listing Table) of interest to Go to the Attribute Details page -> Expand the "Advanced Attribute Properties" section:

- Change the value of "Add to Column Options" to "Yes"

  - Select "Yes" to add this attribute to the list of column options in the product grid.
- Change the value of "Use in Filter Options" to "Yes"

  - Select "Yes" to add this attribute to the list of filter options in the product grid.

Click on the "Save" button to commit these changes to the Database.

Out of the Box the `ts_dimensions_length` / `ts_dimensions_width` / `ts_dimensions_height` attributes will have both the "Use in Filter Options" and "Add to Column Options" values set to "No"

*Source:* Line 100 - 143 in `vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Setup/SetupData.php`

[image: Line 100 - 143 Temando_Shipping SetupData.php]

[image: For Example - ts_dimensions_length]

**To View a Desired Product Attribute(s) in the Edit_Product_Details Page :**

Login to Magento Admin UIX (aka Magento Backend) -> Stores -> Attributes : Attribute Set -> Click on the row (in the Attribute-Set Listing Table) associated with the Attribute_Set assigned to the Product(s) of interest:

Move the Attribute(s) of interest from the "Unassigned Attributes" column to the Appropriate section/sub-section of interest under the "Groups" column.

[image: Assign Attributes to Attribute_Set]

Click on the "Save" button to commit these changes to the Database.